# how to prevent script injections centrally for .net core mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core, xss

I just need some opinions on implementing a logic to centrally check if there is no scripts added to the inputs.

I am planning to use antiXSS (Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment("value")) and check the output if it is null, meaning it could contain script and handle the error.
I could come up with an logic to through the model properties and check the value and if there is anything suspicious throws an error.

I wonder if there is a better way of handling this injections for all input fields in one go rather than adding validations for each field.

Lets say if I have a model like:

```
public class Login {
   public string Email {get; set;}
   public string Password {get; set;}
}
```

Can I just add some sort of filtering to check if non of the inputs contain any scripts before hitting the action rather than adding some attributes to the model or validation express and then do html encode individually for each field and then throw an error.

I want something very at top so I don't go through each actions or model and make some changes.

Comment: Caveat on that [deprecated library](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/pull/8800). The discussion essentially points to [Prevent Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cross-site-scripting?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Thank you. Yes that's what I need to do basically for all views and actions. However, the application I am working on at the moment is not set up properly and I was thinking to have an action filter for all actions and catch the injections at a very top layer. Otherwise, I need to make lots of changes in the code.

Comment: You can look into [Action Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#action-filters) and apply it globally or at controller level. Hth

Comment: yes, action filter is the best way doing that. I have created my own logic to encode the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used filter action and added such a code to check for string type of any model in the request and encode it. It works perfectly fine for us.

```
public static class HttpEncode
{
    public static void ParseProperties(this object model)
    {
        if (model == null) return;

        if (IsPropertyArrayOrList(model.GetType()))
        {
            ParsePropertiesOfList(model);
        }
        else
        {
            GetAllProperties(model).ForEach(t => EncodeField(t, model));
        }
    }

    private static void ParsePropertiesOfList(object model)
    {
        foreach (var item in (IEnumerable) model)
        {
            ParseProperties(item);
        }
    }

    private static List<PropertyInfo> GetAllProperties(object value) => value?.GetType()?.GetProperties()?.ToList();

    private static void EncodeField(PropertyInfo p, object arg)
    {
        try
        {
            if (p.GetIndexParameters().Length != 0 || p.GetValue(arg) == null)
                return;

            if (IsUserDefinedClass(p.PropertyType) && p.CanWrite)
            {
                ParseProperties(p.GetValue(arg));
            }
            else if (IsPropertyArrayOrList(p.PropertyType) && p.CanWrite)
            {
                ParseArrayOrListProperty(p, arg);
            }
            else if (p.PropertyType == typeof(string) && p.CanWrite)
            {
                var encodedValue = HtmlEncode(p.GetValue(arg)?.ToString());
                SetPropertyValue(p, arg, encodedValue);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // ignored
        }
    }

    private static void ParseArrayOrListProperty(PropertyInfo p, object arg)
    {
        if (p.GetValue(arg) is string[] || p.GetValue(arg) is List<string>)
        {
            SetPropertyValueOfStaringArrayType(p, arg);
        }
        else
        {
            ParsePropertiesOfList(p.GetValue(arg));
        }
    }

    private static void SetPropertyValueOfStaringArrayType(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, object arg)
    {
        if (propertyInfo.GetValue(arg) is string[] stringValue)
        {
            var result = new List<string>();
            stringValue.ToList().ForEach(l => result.Add(HtmlEncode(l)));
            SetPropertyValue(propertyInfo, arg, result.Any() ? result.ToArray() : null);
        }
        else if (propertyInfo.GetValue(arg) is List<string> listValue)
        {
            var result = new List<string>();
            listValue.ForEach(l => result.Add(HtmlEncode(l)));
            SetPropertyValue(propertyInfo, arg, result.Any() ? result : null);
        }
    }

    private static bool IsUserDefinedClass(Type type) =>
        type.IsClass &&
        !type.FullName.StartsWith("System.");

    private static bool IsPropertyArrayOrList(Type type) =>
        type.IsArray && type.GetElementType() == typeof(string) ||
        (type != typeof(string) && type.GetInterface(typeof(IEnumerable<>).FullName) != null);

    private static void SetPropertyValue(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, object allValue, object value)
    {
        propertyInfo.SetValue(allValue, value);
    }

    private static string HtmlEncode(string value) => HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value);

}

   public class EncodeInputsActionFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(
        ActionExecutingContext context,
        ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        ProcessHtmlEncoding(context);
        var resultContext = await next();
        // do something after the action executes; resultContext.Result will be set
    }

    private static void ProcessHtmlEncoding(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.ActionArguments.ToList().ForEach(arg => { arg.Value.ParseProperties(); });
    }
}
```